# How to give multiple if conditions checking in Laravel with validations

Tags: validation, laravel-5.1

When I'm submitting the form with values it is checking the conditions first time only after when I update the value in form field it is not checking the if conditions only checking form validation rules and submitting data only how to give all conditions and validation rules ,I added rules in model i.e every field required only
this is my controller code:
 public function addtaskdetail(){

```
  $inputs=Input::all();

  $data2 =DB::table('Task_Headers')->where('id','=',$inputs['TaskHeader_id'])->first();

  $abc =$data2->Estimated_cost;
  $dur=$data2->Duration;
  $pcd=$data2->Planned_Completion_Date;
  $xyz = $inputs['Unit_cost'];
  $durtd=$inputs['Duration'];
  $pcdtd=$inputs['Planned_Completion_Date'];


     if($xyz>$abc){

   Session::flash('flash_message','Unit cost must be less than estimated cost ');
   }

if($pcdtd>$pcd){

Session::flash('flash_message1','planned completion date  must be less than planned completi0n date in TaskHeader ');
}
 if($durtd>$dur){

   Session::flash('flash_message2','Duration  must be less than Duration in TaskHeader ');
  }


   $validation = Validator::make($inputs, TaskDetail::$rules);

  if($validation->fails()){


    return Redirect::to('taskdetailaddform')->withErrors($validation)->withInput();


  }else{

    $input=Input::only('TaskHeader_id','description','Duration','Planned_Completion_Date','currency_code','Unit_cost','Vendor_id','status');

    $data=new TaskDetail;    
  $data->TaskHeader_id = $input['TaskHeader_id'];
    $data->description = $input['description'];
    $data->Duration = $input['Duration'];
    $data->Planned_Completion_Date = $input['Planned_Completion_Date'];
    $data->currency_code = $input['currency_code'];
    $data->Unit_cost = $input['Unit_cost'];
    $data->Vendor_id = $input['Vendor_id'];

    $data->status = $input['status'];

    $data->save();


   return redirect('taskdetailinfo');
}}
```

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

thanks for fixing my grammer mistakes and suggestions.
i got solution for that question i posted.

Comment: Would you please provide more details, the complete controller code, where are those if statements?